# Is there a cloud rendering service for baking in Cycles?

Tags: baking

Id like to cloud bake multiple 8K textures. 
Is there an add on that allows me to do this on a render farm?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this might be something for you: 
https://render.st/blender-render-farm/

There is also a plugin for Blender:
https://render.st/faq/

You can try it for (free) one day and 1$ and it supports baking of physics and bake caches.

Comment: It sems that's not what they offer: 
"RenderStreet fully supports uploading your own bake caches to use for rendering your project."